# Broadcast Receiver Android - нужно ли использовать несколько receiver'ов

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, broadcasting

Балуюсь с broadcast, получилось создать и зарегистрировать 2 receiver'a. Хотелось бы узнать, как дело обстоит на практике, обходятся ли одним receiver'ом и проверяют на intent на action или же бывает, что регистрируют несколько?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте столько, сколько будет нужно, главное это читаемость кода, можете использовать несколько receiver для определенных задач, это тоже норма.

Comment: Смысл я понял, спасибо!